# jmeter regular expression correlation error

Tags: apache, jmeter

Not able to correlate a value in JMeter, getting an error while running the script.

I have a parameter which consists of 9-digit, and my regular expression Template is [0-9]{9}, but still getting an error. What should be the exact template value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused with "templates" which are "match groups". You should configure your Regular Expression Extractor as follows:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `parameter`
- Regular Expression: `[0-9]{9}`
- Template: `$0$`

  [image: Regex Demo]

Refer extracted value as `parameter` where required.

References:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) User Manual Chapter
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: My script is getting pass but while checking on DB , there is no increment of response count. My actual scenario is like , the parameter which I want to correlate , that gets generated from server side for each User, and I have to pass that value(or some Function) in on my script for that parameter. Earlier in LR(LoadRunner 9.5/12.1) I used to select that 9 digit number for the recorded script and go for correlation option, and it does work.